# Expensify WP7 test framework

Tags: windows-phone-7, command, voice, speech

Can we use the Expensify Frame work to test Voice Commands on Emulator/Device..

Answer (score 0):

The feels like this should be possible, but isn't something that I've already coded.

To achieve it, you'd have to setup some sort of playback system to create the audio voice commands. This could be done, for example, by using audio playback triggered from C# SpecFlow steps on the PC - e.g. using something like DirectShow/quartz - http://csharp-slackers.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/playing-wav-or-mp3.html

This audio would then be played out and captured back into the emulator through the speakers and microphone on the host PC - just make sure they are positioned appropriately.

Comment: Approach seems to be OK incase if we want to test on emulator. Is there any way I can play WAV file out (for outside people hear) and capture the same on to MIC simunataniously programatically...

Comment: How can I test the Voice commands using Expensify Frame work on Windows Phone Real Device?

Comment: For playing WAV file out, check out the directshow link in the answer... for real device testing, you'll need to adjust with the framework initialisation parameters.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on framework initialisation parameters to test voice commands on real device from Expensify Framework... I appereciate your response...

Comment: You need to override the RemoteUrl in https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework/blob/master/Client/AutomationClient/Configuration.cs

Comment: Thanks for the details. But what I am looking is I will have Expensify test framework runnig on my PC and WP7 device connected to USB port of my PC. In this setup.. WP7 waits for Voice Commands (MS Tell app which gets launhced when we long press start button on the device) and I want to input the speech from frame work (basically automate testing of voice app)...Can you please guide how can I acheive this..

Comment: I think maybe you need to ask a long detailed question - and also maybe you need to try this for yourself. I'm not sure I can assist at the level you seem to need. What do you have working already?

Comment: I have written windows phone Applicaion with reference to AutomationClient.dll in it.

I have connected the WP7 device to PC with USB.

When windows phone Applicaion gets launched does it establishes the HTTP connection with the Expensify Test framewok running on PC?

Once the connection is estbalished does all the command given at Emuhost command line (on PC) will be send to the real device?

Comment: Mouse and keyboard emulation to control the emulator device - this is needed to do things like physical touches, hard button presses (and other emulator interactions when the app isn't running - e.g. taking photos). For devices attached using USB: 1 and 2 are available --------------------------------------------Is this limitation because the current implementation on Expensify framework used PC mouse and keyboard drivers to simulate this? Is is possible to send the command over the HTTP connection established between PC and real device to simulate the keyboard?

Comment: From conversations in comments, I've no idea what your question is. Please write a new clear question if you can - and I will try to help.